# Javascript setter - How to get the name of the setter inside of the setter?

Tags: javascript, setter

So I need to get the name of the setter that is called when I assign a value to it. Like this:

```
var b = {};

var a = {
 set hey(value) {
  b[<name of setter>] = value;
 }
}
```

I want the name of setter to be 'hey', so `b.hey` equals the value you set `a.hey` to.

I've been searching for a couple of days now and can't find an answer to my problem. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: check this out.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: Why would you want a setter to set a value of in a different object?

Comment: But you *know* the name of the setter? You just wrote it one line above it? Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: The setter is assigned a name based on some other logic. So you can't really predict what the name is going to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `arguments.callee.name` to get the function name, slice off the leading `set`, and assign it to a property of `b`:

```js
var b = {};
var a = {
  set hey(value) {
    const name = arguments.callee.name.slice(4);
    b[name] = value;
  }
}
a.hey = 'foo';

console.log(b);
```

This will fail in strict mode, though - you might consider using a `Proxy` instead for `a`, if possible:

```js
var b = {};
var a = new Proxy({}, { set: (_, prop, val) => {
  b[prop] = val;
}});
a.hey = 'foo';

console.log(b);
```

Comment: `callee`? really? today?

Comment: I'm not sure there's another way while preserving `a` as a plain object. The proxy is definitely better, if it's an option, of course

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can finally continue with my project thanks to you!